# proof that $ \sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} a_n = \sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} a_{p(n)} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Proof that if $ \forall_{n > n_0 - 1}, a_n > 0 $ and $p$ is permutation in $ N_{n_0} $ then
$$ \sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} a_n = \sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} a_{p(n)} $$ 
regardless of whether or not there is convergence

Hi, I have to do this task but in my opinion there is nothing special to do because addition is **commutative**. But I have some doubt about correctness of my thinking.

Probably I won't ask you about this but in next question I need to proof this in additional assumption:
Proof thesis assuming that the series is only convergent absolutely.

If commutative of addition is right way of thinking, then there is no difference between first and second task...

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The commutativity of addition is clear for finite sums. It's not clear for infinite sums, and indeed for conditionally convergent series is not true---look up the "Riemann rearrangement theorem".

Comment: Commutativity doesn't immediately give you this, because the sums are limits over finite sums (they are not finite sums themselves, which you can apply commutativity to). So you have to prove that these limits are equivalent.

Comment: There definitely is something to do.

Comment: Chmm, can somebody give me a hint?